# How to deploy a java program to a web site

Tags: web-apps

Thanks in advance for any assistance or insights regarding my question.
So I have written a program in java 8 that is fully functional and executes and performs correctly from the jvm command line.
Now, I would like to wrap it into a GUI of some sort and deploy it to my personal website where users can then execute/run it from within their browser, whether it be desktop or mobile device.
There are many options to do this, I'm sure. But before I begin researching them I thought it best to ask in the community for their thoughts and opinions regarding best solutions.
What I have for my "tool set" so far is eclipse ide, java 8 jdk/jre, javafx, maven, MySQL, junit, spring, and hibernate.

Thank you for any all responses and insights that can lead me to the best path to follow.

Steven

Answer (score 2):

Your Question is really too broad for this web site. And you do not provide specifics on which to make a particular recommendation. So I'll be briefly cover some possibilities.

## Java Applet

[*Java Applet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) was the old way to run a Java app within a web browser. Indeed the original purpose of Java was applets. But the connection between Java and the web browsers proved to be flawed in many ways including notorious security vulnerabilities. Similarly, running [Adobe Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash) in the browser proved unsafe and unworkable. Java Applet technology is now being deprecated by both Oracle and the browser makers, as is Flash.

## Java Web Start

[*Java Web Start*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) is a framework for distributing your app conveniently to the user via web browser. The app actually downloads to the user’s machine to be run locally, outside of the web browser. This is a good way to distribute apps with a user interface based on [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), [Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)), or [Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit). Java itself is designed for security. This concern for security includes putting apps deployed with Java Web Start in a [“sandbox”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)) to limit the app’s access to the user’s computer’s resources without additional permissions extended by the user.

You mention [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) in your Question. This confuses me as you also state the app is [command-line driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface). If you actually have written a JavaFX interface app, then Java Web Start might be the avenue to explore. However, you also mention a database and running on your server, in which case you should read on to learn about servlets.

## Java Servlet

[*Java Servlet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) technology is what has driven much of the Web for many years now. You can write very small apps (servlet) that are automatically invoked when a user’s web browser makes a request to your web server. Your servlet app dynamically generates the text of the HTML for a web page to be delivered back to the web browser. You deploy your servlet in a [servlet container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) on your server computer. That container handles all the work of interacting with the web browser, accepting an incoming request, invoking your servlet, and returning your generated HTML back to the web browser. You servlet app need not do any of that “plumbing”.

You can choose among a [couple dozen Servlet containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_servers#Java). Pick the lightest, simplest container laden with the fewest libraries/technologies that happen to meet your needs.

- If you only need the Java Servlet and maybe JavaServer Pages technologies, choose a simpler lighter container such as [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) or [Eclipse Jetty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)).
- If you make use of additional Java technologies, you may be able to add libraries to Tomcat/Jetty, or you can adopt a product bundling those libraries in complying with the [Java EE Web Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_profile), such as [Apache TomEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_TomEE).
- If you make use of even more Java technologies, you may want to move up to the still bigger and heavier products that comply with the full [Java EE edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition).

Caveat: Java Servlet technology is inherently [multi-threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)). You *must* [learn about concurrency](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127932.Java_Concurrency_in_Practice) to avoid terrible conflicts in the operation of your app.

## Servlet frameworks

For a simple app, you could write your own servlet by hand. For a more complicated app, you will want to leverage a framework for generating the content. There are *many* such frameworks from which you may choose.

You may want more than plain HTML in your web app, leading you to JavaScript, CSS, and more. All of this can get quite complex. For my recommendation to solving that complexity, read on to learn about Vaadin.

### Vaadin

Personally, the only web app framework I find palatable is the [Vaadin Framework](https://vaadin.com/framework). With Vaadin, you can write your app entirely in pure Java and have the user-interface generated automatically in HTML, CSS, JavaScript, DOM, WebSockets, and Push, without you having to learn any of those technologies. All Java on the server-side, no Java on the client-side. Truly amazing technology.

I have built a few Vaadin apps, deployed on [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org), with [Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition) 8, on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), storing data in the enterprise-quality [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org) database.

Try the [Vaadin Grid demo](https://vaadin.com/grid), the [QuickTickets Dashboard](http://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/) example app, the [Sampler](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/), and the older [Reindeer Demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme).

Vaadin works with all three common [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)s: [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org), and [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)). Vaadin is now entirely [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven)-driven. So you may not need the formerly common Vaadin plugin available in an edition for each IDE. At least with IntelliJ and NetBeans (and maybe Eclipse - not sure), you can just use pure Maven without any Vaadin-specific plugin. The Vaadin company provides a pair of Maven archetypes from which you can build your app: a single module for learning and possibly deploying, and a multi-module for when you have more experience (or you already are a multi-module Maven maven).

I have used all three IDEs for Vaadin work (long story, don't ask). I have found all of them to be extremely powerful and flexible as well as quite awkwardly-designed and clumsy-to-use. So expect a learning curve in any case. IntelliJ Ultimate is becoming my favorite, but any of the three can get the job done. Maven itself is a challenge to learn and master, but at least that learning will be useful in most all your Java work, not just Vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it seems that you are starting with web applications I suggest you use [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io). It allows you to easily bootstrap a web application choosing amongst several frameworks and libraries (back end, frontend, database), including MySql and Spring.